# Exclude multiples values splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula

I want to make a splunk search where i exclude all the event whose transid corelate with transid of an event that contain the string "[error]".

here is my current search

```
*base-search*
| eval rm_id=if(like(_raw, "%[error]%") , 0, transid)
```

i have to exclude all the values in the "rm_id" field from my search

Comment: what does your data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIUI, if there is an event containing the string "error" then all events with the same transid value are to be discarded, correct?

If so, then you can use the `transaction` command.  The command groups events with common field values into single events, which then can be filtered.  The `transaction` command can be slow and memory-intensive.

```
*base-search*
| transaction transid
| search NOT "error"
```

Another method uses subsearches to identify transids that have "error" in them so the main search can avoid those transids.  Subsearches have a limit of 50,000 results.

```
*base-search* NOT [ search *base-search* "error" | fields transid | format ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude events that contain "`[error]`", just do the following - it's *much* simpler:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp transid=* NOT "[error]"
| <rest of spl goes here>
```

Comment: it's not exactly what i want to do. I want to exclude all event that have the same id as the event that contain the string [error]